# How to: Vue3 composition API plugin

Tags: vue.js, socket.io, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How to create a plugin that works with the Vue3 composition API.

For example a Socket.io plugin which can be accessed in every component.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To create any plugin (example: Socket.io) for vue3 and use it in your composition API component and in your vue2/option api component.

Create the plugin itself and add it to your `plugins` folder

**Socket.io 3.0.1** is used

Plugin:

```js
import { io } from 'socket.io-client'

export default {
  install: (app, { connection, options }) => {
    const socket = io(connection, options)
    app.config.globalProperties.$socket = socket

    app.provide('socket', socket)
  }
}
```

In your **main.js** add the following

```js
import Socketio from '@/plugins/Socket.io'

app.use(Socketio, {
    connection: 'http://localhost:4001',
    options: {
        // Your Socket.io options here
    }
})
```

**main.js** example

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'
import Socketio from '@/plugins/Socket.io'

const app = createApp(App)

app.use(store)
app.use(router)
app.use(Socketio, {
    connection: 'http://localhost:4001',
    options: {
        // Your Socket.io options here
    }
})

app.mount('#app')
```

### **Usages:**

**Option API:** `this`

In the option api you can use `this.$socket` to access the socket

```html
<template>
// HTML here
</template>

<script>
export default {
   mounted () {
       // You can use the socket like shown below
       this.$socket.on('foo', () => {
           console.log('bar')
       })
   }
}
</script>
```

**Option API:** `inject`

In the option api you also have the possibility to **inject** the plugin

```html
<template>
// HTML here
</template>

<script>
import { inject } from 'vue'

export default {
   mounted () {
       const socket = inject('socket')
       // You can use the socket like shown below
       socket.on('foo', () => {
           console.log('bar')
       })
   }
}
</script>
```

**Composition API** `inject`

In the composition API your should use `inject`

```html
<template>
    {{ bar }}
</template>

<script>
import { ref, inject } from 'vue'

export default {
    setup() {
        const socket = inject('socket')
        return { ...foo(socket) }
    }
}

function foo(socket) {
    const bar = ref('')
    socket.on('foo', (value) => {
        bar.value = value
    })

    return {
        bar
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I'm using Vue2 with the composition API and in my case I get the error "provide is not a function" from within the plugin. Does someone have an idea, why?