# Importing modules globally in Quasar / Vue

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

Is there a way to globally import (import statement in only one file and imported only once) JavaScript modules so that the imported module is available throughout the entire Vue / Quasar application?

I was trying to achieve this using Quasar's boot files. But when I have to access the global property it is a whole lot of 3 more lines to make the global property available in the current component. (specially via the composition api).

Is there an easier / clean way to do this?

```js
import { getCurrentInstance } from 'vue'
const MyComponent = {
  setup() {
    const internalInstance = getCurrentInstance()
    // access to globalProperties
    internalInstance.appContext.config.globalProperties 
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/64782386/10706046 . Though I agree it'd be much cleaner to eg. create a Vue plugin that allows adding new properties to the context (setup(props,context)). If it answers your question, please consider marking is as duplicate

Comment: @ArturTagisow whats mentioned in the link is not so different from what I have already tried. I just need to be able to use certain global objects without having to import them or inject them in every file. For an example, think about a file where we store constants, we will have to use the constants throughout the application.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/ How about this?